# Why do the objects in this rigid body simulation rotate too slowly?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I was attempting to simulate a bowling ball impacting a set of pins, however the pins just slide away instead of going flying like they should:

[image]

As you can see, the origins are in the correct place.

What is causing this?

**[Blendfile](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/24509)**

Comment: Could you post your settings for the rigid bodies? I tried to rebuild your scene and it works just fine here.

Comment: @Haunt_House I linked to my [.blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/24509), can you use that?

Comment: I have it open right now. Sorry, my brain doesn't get much food nowadays. I tipped one of your victims 45 degrees and it's tilting veeeery slowly. so there's simulation going on, but for some reason, the rotation is extremely damped.

Comment: @Haunt_House It looks like the origins are way off, but they aren't..

Comment: Did the solution work for you?

Comment: @Haunt_House sorry, I was afk. That seems to have done it! thanks :)

Comment: One is glad to be of service. Funny enough, if you scale objects down, they not only turn slower, but they start to become quite bouncy. They rock back and forth quite a lot before settling on the ground.

Comment: @Haunt_House Odd. perhaps a bug? I though the new viewport bullet physics system was supposed to be able to handle scaling.. :/

Comment: More like a missing feature. Feel free to submit it anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your pins are scaled to 0.144. Seems like the simulation doesn't like that. Apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and you should be fine.

Comment: Probably something to do with the mass calculation

Comment: @GregZaal wouldn't that mean the mass would be 330 times smaller, so the pins would accelerate 330 times faster? **F** = m **a** and all that.

Comment: When you clear scale (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) it'll be bigger, so more mass.