# rigid body not rotating after collision

Tags: rigidbody

I was trying to recreate a bowling alley in Blender 2.90.

The [YouTuber "Default Cube" made a series of 3 episodes on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdCFjpEUqJc) where he showed how he did it so I watched the videos and tried to make it without watching the Videos again. I think the only thing I did not like he did was to use real life sizes and weights.

My problem now is that the pins have no rotation and don't even fall. I [read that it's probably because the scale is not set to 1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3280).

I tried to apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> but get this error

> `Cannot apply to a multi user: Object "Cylinder.001", Mesh "Cylinder", aborting`

I tried to re and dis-enable rigid body physics for all the objects multiple times with no success.

here's a [video how it looks like](https://streamable.com/8ljjb4)

[Files for the pin, the ball, and everything combined](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19QxkCF-En-_L0QaLskfrJ9Ulob3WOT-u)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is preventing you from applying scale is that more than one object in your scene shares the same mesh.  This object was *instanced* instead of *duplicated*.

[image]

The solution **should** be to right click on one of the offending meshes in the Outliner and select Make Single User, but this is evidently not yet implemented.

Instead, what may be easiest is to duplicate each object in place with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, cancel movement with RMB and delete the originals.

When each object has unique mesh data, you'll be able to apply scale to all of them.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it's working :)

Comment: Good to hear. :)  Just upvote answers that are helpful and well structured.  You can also mark one as "the solution" but it may not be appropriate in this case since there was more than one thing happening, it's up to you.

Comment: I tried to upvote but couldn't. I first had to get 15 rep :)  Now implementing the whole scene into camera tracked footage :)

Answer (score 1):

For good physics calculation it's better to apply the scale, see the scale of your cube, it's 0.145, do the same for the ball, and it will roll fine:

[image]